# Updating texture not working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Not working update on this texture. The code is an abbreviated version and I need it so. I need to update the texture. How would I be able to do this in Swift in SpriteKit?

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {        
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.ball && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.coin
    {
        vyhodnoceni()
        screen(2)

    }}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    vysledekHvezdyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: starString1!)}

func vyhodnoceni(){
starString1 = "hvezdy1"}

func screen(number: Int){
    if number == 2 {
        vysledekHvezdy = SKSpriteNode(texture: vysledekHvezdyTexture)
        vysledekHvezdy.size = CGSize(width: screenSize.width / 2, height: screenSize.height / 10.5)
        vysledekHvezdy.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2.3)
        vysledekHvezdy.zPosition = 11
        vysledekHvezdy.alpha = 0.0
        vysledekHvezdy.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.7))
        self.addChild(vysledekHvezdy)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us specifically what is not working.

Comment: texture does not update

Comment: :) - that is not very specific mate. You have not given us much code so it is difficult to see what you are trying to do. Does the Sprite appear with an initial texture at all? When is the texture supposed to update? From what texture to what texture is the update required? Are you getting any errors? ...

Comment: Collision sends two functions, "screen" displays the information on the display and the "vysledek" evaluates the results. The problem is that the texture does not know the variable of the function "vysledek" and therefore does not update. In "vysledek" but I have a lot if the conditions that define the outcome.

Comment: there is no method "vysledek" in the posted code, do you mean "vyhodnoceni"? You only change the texture in the update method, why is that not in "vyhodnoceni"? Still not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do to update textures is:

```
let changeTexture = SKAction.animateWithTextures([page1], timePerFrame: 0.1)
bg.runAction(changeTexture)
```

let me know if that works.